# yii2 route config for modules instead of controllers

Tags: routes, yii2

I'm in need to configure all of my models and controllers except SiteControllers as modules. I've managed to get simple views working, but can't get around with other controller actions.

To elaborate what I'm talking about, routes should be as following:

```
example.com => app/site/index
example.com/page => app/modules/page/default/index
example.com/page/<slug> => app/modules/page/default/view/<slug>
example.com/submit/1 => app/modules/page/default/submit/1
```

The first three are working as they should, but what about the following? Current `urlManager` is:

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [           
            '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>/view',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>/view',
        ],
    ],
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If your models, controllers  and view are coded like a Yii2 module require you don't need special route config  .. you  simple should declare a proper entry in module section of your confi/main.php

eg .. i have create a module migr  in a my personal vendor location and i setted the module in config/main.php this way

```
'modules' => [
    ........
    'migr' => [ // dfenx module for migration via web without console command
        'class' => 'vendor\myVendorName\migr\Module',
    ],
```

the routing is automatically assigned using eg:

```
 myproject/backend/web/index.php/migr/my-action
```

for the url don't invoke direcly  but use UrlHelpers

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

Url::to(['module/controller/action', 'id' => $id]);
```

in this way the url is generated properly respect the config  in urlManager

Comment: I understand that, but as you can see, when I configure my models and controllers like that, the extra `default` controller parameter is required in the URL for it to work. I would like to lose that part from the URL. Even more, pretty url is currently not working for the view. Eg `site.com/module/controller/action?id=1` is working, but `site.com/module/controller/action/1` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: post your  urlManager  configuration in config/main.php  component

Comment: I've updated the original post. Or should I add extra routing rules in each module config?

Comment: Could you see me a a sample of how you call  /invoke the site.com/module/controller/action/1 url ?

Comment: site.com/module/controller/action/1 would be invoked as site.com/module/action/1, so just without the controller part. I actually got it working thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27959286/4043597), the only thing is that this solution is not accepting pretty URL id variable passing. Eg `site.com/module/action?id=1` works, but `site.com/module/action/1` does not.

Comment: I have added a suggestion for the url .. hope useful